# How to pass a ng-repeat variable in ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have ng-repeat in first line of code , in the next line I need to create a dynamic variable based on what I get in ng-repeat.

code would look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="head in arrayofhead">
  <span ng-if="canIbecreated_{{head}}">I am created!!</span>
</div>
```

where

```
arrayofhead = ["1","2","3"];
```

but this produces an error while similarly I can pass {{$index}} in this easily.

Why this ditching is present in Angularjs?

on Controller I would do

```
var canIbecreated_1="false";
var canIbecreated_2="true";
var canIbecreated_3="false";
```

To crate and not to create the span.

Comment: what does canIBeCreated do? Is it meant to be a function or a string or what?

Comment: @cbass it's a variable. On controller I would set it's value false or true,to create or to not create the span.

Comment: Why not use a better suited data structure, e.g. `.heads = [{label: 1, canBeCreated: true}, ...]`? Constructing variable names is often a [bad smell](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... ng-if="someFunc(head)" ...
```

Inside the `ng-repeat` block. That should do the trick.

Comment: what you are saying is correct. But I don't want to pass it in a function. I want to create a dynamic variable on the basis of it's value.

Comment: Why not have something like `canIbecreated[1] = false` and so on? Wouldn't that be more convenient?

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach too. But I did what Yoshi said. Should I accept your answer, although It's comments where real solution lies.